# Spring IO file based pagination

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-io

I have a large file around 20MB and I am using spring Boot for my REST API now task is client will send the fileName and I need to write controller method which will provide the number of pages in that file. There is also a records per page attribute which I am setting in the application.properties. Now the next task is client will ask fileName with a page number and I have to provide content for that page.

I was wondering if there is spring pagination for files. I am finding for database but none so far for files.

Any help or code in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "pagination for files" ?

Comment: The file is huge so UI wants to show it in form of pages so when user will click for that page  then there will be a AJAX request with filename and pageNumber and I need to respond back with the content for page only. So I need to store this info (mapping of page number to line number) prior so when the request comes I will fetch it and then it from the file and return back to the caller.

Comment: Ok I see, and what kind of file are you processing ? PDF ? Word ?

Comment: Its a text file \n separated.

Comment: Spring won't help you much for this kind of work, you'll have to load and split your file yourself unfortunately !